# Subtotals in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
[[1 3 1]
 [8 9 0]
 [1 3 1]
 [8 4 1]
 [5 1 0]]
```

and I want to produce subtotals (count, sums, averages) for columns 0,1 for each of the 3rd column's values. Can it be done directly in numpy, or do I have to loop the entire array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.histogram()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html):

```
counts = numpy.histogram(data[:,2], bins=range(3))[0]
sums0 = numpy.histogram(data[:,2], bins=range(3), weights=data[:,0])[0]
sums1 = numpy.histogram(data[:,2], bins=range(3), weights=data[:,1])[0]
```

`bins` must be adapted to reflect the values occuring in the third column.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have many values in the third column, you can do it like this for each value (supposed your array is `data`):

```
np.mean(data[data[:,2] == 1], axis = 0)
np.sum(data[data[:,2] == 1], axis = 0)
```

Otherwise you can loop for the different values in the third column.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to do this using pandas (http://pandas.sourceforge.net/)

```
In [35]: from pandas import DataMatrix

In [36]: dm = DataMatrix(a)

In [37]: dm
Out[37]: 
     0           1           2           
0    1           3           1          
1    8           9           0          
2    1           3           1          
3    8           4           1          
4    5           1           0          

In [38]: dm.groupby(dm[2]).sum()
Out[38]: 
     0           1           2           
0    13          10          0          
1    10          10          3          


In [39]: dm.groupby(dm[2]).mean()
Out[39]: 
     0           1           2           
0    6.5         5           0          
1    3.333       3.333       1          

In [48]: dm[2].groupby(dm[2]).agg(len)
Out[48]: 
0    2
1    3
```

But this might be a bit of overkill =) (more on groupby: http://pandas.sourceforge.net/groupby.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, compute the difference between your elements and the last column:

```
check = data[:,:2]-data[:,2].reshape((-1,1))
```

Then, you can sum the elements of check that are equal to zero, in each row

```
sum(check==0, axis=1)
```

This returns a array of length "number of rows" with the count of occurences of the value of the last column in the first two columns.

What you want is not fully clear to me, however.

If you just want to sum and average data, the sum, mean and std methods on ndarrays allow you to do it "axis-wise":

```
data[:,:2].mean(axis=1)
data[:,:2].sum(axis=1)
```